# How to implement reCaptcha V3 in Angular 11?

Tags: angular, recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, recaptcha-enterprise

I have a project in Angular 11.2 which is very difficult to update to a higher version of Angular.
I was able to implement reCaptcha V2 but I have not been able to implement either V3 or Enterprise.

What would be the most optimal solution to implement reCaptcha V3 or Enterprise  (without user interaction) in this version of Angular?

I tried reCaptcha versions: 7.0.2, 8.0.1, 9.0.0, 10.0.0 without any result.